# How can I install GTX260 Drivers on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm trying to install GTX260 drivers on 32 bit ubuntu.

Gedit will not open the file. When run, the file says I'm running 'x server' and that the correct graphics card is not installed.

When I turn use Service Stop on GDM (which google led me to believe was the way to stop X server), there is a black screen and text input doesn't seem to do anything.

The Nvidia-current and Nvidia-Settings packages have broken dependencies(dkms and screen-resolution-extra).

Checking other similar threads and trying the solutions presented there did not avail me.

I'm a noobie.

Comment: Hi sean did you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers i recommend you read it. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you let us know what version of Ubuntu you're using, both Distro and Release Version?

Mainstream Ubuntu doesn't use GDM anymore, so I was curious which version you're using.

== More Technical, Assuming Answer ==
(assuming Mainstream Ubuntu, 12.04LTS and up)

To install the Nvidia drivers, I would recommend using nvidia's drivers from their website. Here's what you'll need:

1. Install the kernel headers (if they're not already) (`apt-get install linux-headers-generic`)
2. Download the 32bit driver from nvidia's site
3. Stop the display manager (`service lightdm stop`)
4. Run the installation (`sh ~/Downloads/nvidia-install-file-here.sh`)
   Restart the machine

You'll need to prefix those commands with `sudo` in order to gain superuser privileges.

Comment: Also, replace "nvidia-install-file-here.sh" with the name of the file you downloaded from nvidia